# Unable to install Windows on new SSD

Tags: windows, installation, ssd, grub

I recently bought a new SSD (OCZ Trion 100, if that matters) to replace it with the one my laptop (Fujitsu LifeBook SH531) has. I took all the files from the old HDD I needed and then I removed the old disk and put in the new one, I did this without any problem. The problem came when I turned the laptop on, my plan was to install Windows 10 on it with an USB i already used once (so I know it works). When I turn it on and after the screen where I can access the BIOS menu appears a black screen with the text ''launching grub'' and then turns into this command console (https://s4.postimg.org/7irvbasr1/1480192509427_14672057.jpg) instead of the thing it should to install Windows 10. I searched info about this grub thing but I still have no idea on what to do.
The BIOS recognises both the USB and the SSD (https://s17.postimg.org/es3lwp7xr/1480192829523_1674561459.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if you just copied all files with windows from old disk (without install new copy of windows into SSD) then it is the problem.

error on image is that grub cant find EFI partition or bootloader files.
I think you should install windows and (also every OS you want to use) as a fresh copy. then just copy all other data from old disk.